# how to call event handler code from javascript code

Tags: asp.net, javascript

how do you call a server-side button (onclick event) in javascript in
ASP.net (VB.net or C#)

Comment: where u need to call? can u show ur code?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these links will assist you:

- [Calling ASP.NET server-side events using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JavaScriptAndServerEvents.aspx)
- [ASP.NET – How to call a server-side method from client-side JavaScript](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use onClientClick

Comment: i want to call server side event fron javascript.

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario